# Reconstructing A Chess Game #3 (fanmade)

Tags: story, chess, retrograde-analysis

I'm a huge fan of the first 2 [parts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73606/reconstructing-a-chess-game-2) made by @Evargalo, so i'll try too

My teacher once told me a strategy to defeat the enemy in the second turn.
I was so excited (:P) I forgot it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only known mate in 2 from the starting position is, as Black:

> 1. f3 (or f4) e5 (or e6) 2. g4 Qh4#

Comment: Also known as fool's mate. :)